# StereoSGBM cannot handle negative minDisparity

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

When I have a positive minimum disparity value (calculated from feature matches), I get a nice disparity map from `StereoSGBM`, but when I have it negative I get a nearly blank disparity map.

Is it possible that the implementation of SGBM in OpenCV doesn't support a negative minimum disparity?

Comment: I ran into the same issue almost a year later. Were you able to solve it?